# How to configure a different main menu for each language on a multilingual site?

Tags: routes, i18n-l10n

I have set up multilingual options on my site, and have a lot of pages in two languages.

I can't work out how to have a different main menu for the two languages. Under `Structure->Menu->Settings`, it says "Source for the Main links", and I'm adding all menu links to the "Main menu" there. However, this means I just get one big menu with all the items in both languages.

What I want is when the page is in English, the main menu is in English, and when in Chinese, the main menu is in Chinese. How to set that up?

Comment: The menu translation module of i18n suit provides this facility. Read: https://www.drupal.org/node/1113982

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the **[i18n Menu Translation](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/i18n/tree/i18nmenu)** sub-module is enabled (it is one of the [Internationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) sub-modules).

Edit the menu to be translated, by navigating to admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu/edit (for the "main menu"). From there it should be possible to select the **translation mode** you want, e.g. *Translate and Localize*.

After doing so, when editing a menu link, there should be a new link **Translate** to actually translate the menu entry. Refer to the [Multilingual Guide](https://www.drupal.org/node/1113982) for (way) more details.

Miltilingual sites are really fun in D7 (way better then it was in D6, and D8 promises to become more easy to configure). Typical variations (with similar solutions) of this "menu" topic are:

- **translations of blocks**, which requires the Block Languages (i18n_block) submodule to be enabled.
- **translations of taxonomies**, which requires the Taxonomy Translation (i18n_taxonomy) submodule to be enabled.